# React JS Functional component renders twice on onChange event and gets always current value of array and then new value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have a React functional component that renders a JSX that contains a paragraph, a dropdown from Select React JS library and a Line chart from Nivo library.

When I render the component for the first time I have a `useEffect` hook that helps me to retrieve data, a list, from the backend. The data is returned from the backend based on a **mode** value.

This **mode** can be:

- week
- month
- year

and I have a useState for it `const [mode, setMode] = useState("week")`.

The Select dropdown has the `onChange` event listener that helps me set a new mode

`setMode(e.value)` - can be **week**, **month** or **year**

When I set a new mode, it goes back to the backend and retrieves a new list with data.

My problem is the following one:

1. I select a new value from the dropdown
2. My component re-renders and gets the current value of my array
3. Then it changes the **mode** with the new value
4. Then the `useEffect` gets the new data based on the new mode and re-renders with the new list.

For example:

My current value on the mode is **week**. Data comes from the backend and renders correctly in the chart. I select a new mode, **month** and call `setMode("month")`. 
First things that happen:

1. The component re-renders
2. Gets current data for the chart which is **week**
3. `useEffect` makes the GET request for the new mode **month** data and sets the new data on the chart
4. If the current mode is **month** and I want to show a chart with **year**. Again on dropdown `onChange` I set the mode to **year**, but first component re-renders get current array value which is **month** and then returns data for **year**.

[image]

**I do not want to get the current value of the array first every time I select a new value from the dropdown. I only want to setMode with the new value and retrieve data from the server with the new list.**

Here is my code:

React Component:

```
import { useFeedbackDistribution } from "../../api/analytics.firebase";
import { DISTRIBUTION_MODE } from "../../utils/query_filters";
// UI
import Loading from "../App/loadingIndicator";
import { ErrorSolid } from "../Errors/error.solid";
import { ResponsiveLine } from "@nivo/line";
import Select from "react-select";

import {
    dayTimeScaleProperties,
    monthTimeScaleProperties,
    yearTimeScaleProperties
} from "../../utils/charts/utils";

const options = [
    { value: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.WEEK, label: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.WEEK },
    { value: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.MONTH, label: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.MONTH },
    { value: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.YEAR, label: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.YEAR }
];

const FeedbackDistributionCard = user => {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState({
        value: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.WEEK,
        label: DISTRIBUTION_MODE.WEEK
    });
    const [{ isLoading, isError, data }] = useFeedbackDistribution(
        mode.value,
        []
    );

    function load(data) {
        switch (mode.value) {
            case DISTRIBUTION_MODE.WEEK:
                return dayTimeScaleProperties(data);
            case DISTRIBUTION_MODE.MONTH:
                return monthTimeScaleProperties(data);
            default:
                return yearTimeScaleProperties(data);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="w-full h-64 sm:w-full md:w-full lg:w-3/4 xl:w-3/4 mb-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
            <div className="w-full h-full ">
                {isError && <ErrorSolid />}
                {isLoading ? (
                    <Loading />
                ) : (
                    <div className="h-full w-full flex-col shadow p-6">
                        <div>
                            <p className="font-bold float-left inline-block">
                                Feedback by {mode.value}
                            </p>
                            <Select
                                className="w-40 z-50 float-right"
                                options={options}
                                onChange={e => {
                                    setMode({ label: e.label, value: e.value });
                                }}
                                value={mode}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="h-full w-full">
                            <FeedbackDistributionLineChart
                                properties={load(data)}
                            /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FeedbackDistributionCard;

const FeedbackDistributionLineChart = ({ properties }) => (
    <ResponsiveLine
        {...properties}
        enablePoints={false}
        enableGridX={false}
        enableGridY={false}
        colors={{ scheme: "category10" }}
        margin={{ top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 40 }}
        animate={true}
        enableSlices={"x"}
        yScale={{
            type: "linear",
            stacked: false
        }}
        axisLeft={{
            legend: "total",
            legendPosition: "middle",
            legendOffset: -30,
            tickValues: 5
        }}
        curve={"basis"}
        enablePointLabel={true}
        useMesh={true}
        enableSlices={false}
    />
);
```

useEffect custom hook

```
const feedbackDistributionReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_INIT":
            return { ...state, isLoading: true, isError: false };
        case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                isError: false,
                data: action.payload
            };
        case "FETCH_ERROR":
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                isError: true,
                data: action.payload
            };
        default:
            throw new Error("Could not fetch feedback distribution");
    }
};

const useFeedbackDistribution = (mode, initialData) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(feedbackDistributionReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: initialData
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        let didCancel = false;
        async function load(mode) {
            console.log(mode);
            dispatch({ type: "FETCH_INIT", payload: null });
            try {
                var feedbackDistribution = firebase
                    .functions()
                    .httpsCallable("feedbackDistribution");
                let result = await feedbackDistribution({ mode: mode });
                var mappedResult = result.data.map(function(item) {
                    var info = { y: item.totalCount, x: item.time };
                    return info;
                });
                const distribution = [
                    {
                        id: "id",
                        data: mappedResult
                    }
                ];

                if (!didCancel) {
                    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: distribution });
                }
            } catch (err) {
                if (!didCancel) {
                    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_ERROR", payload: error });
                }
            }
        }
        load(mode);
        return () => {
            didCancel = true;
        };
    }, [mode]);

    return [state];
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- the problem is you're changing a useState value directly from the onChange which causes a re-render and triggers the hook, you need to dispatch the fetch call directly in the onChange. Good luck! :)